# Inconsistent replies from a Micron N25Q Flash

Tags: spi, flash, nor-flash

I have a board with a MT25QL128ABA SPI Flash from Micron, I am using simple standard SPI (no Quad).
I do the following:

- Send Write Enable
- Send Erase Command (Program Command resp.)
- Repeat: Read the Status Register until Bit 0 reads 0.
- To check for potential errors: Read the flag status register.
  Here I am expecting at least one bit to be set:
- - Either the Ready Bit on 0x80
- - Or one of the error Bits in 0x3A mask (program error etc.)

BUT: sometimes (not very often) I get 0x00 as the Flag Status which means busy.
That does not make sense as the Status Register indicated "not busy".
To make things worse: If I continue as if nothing has happened, I occasionally get (upon reading back) wrong data from flash.
Due to memory limitations, I cannot go back and erase the memory block and program again (the data buffers are gone by now).
What I currently do is repeat the last action I did which most of the time works (but in case of Programming naturally this only works if I am lucky enough that I am not setting a 1 into a cell where the first attempt left a 0).

What can cause this erratic behaviour and how can I work around this?

Comment: Have you verified the hardware timing? What is the spi clock rate? Gpio drive strength, input setup and hold times, spi mode, bypass caps. So many things can ruin you day.

Comment: I'm using 8Mhz, which is not really excessive. CPU is a C8051F580 which does not support GPIO drive strength settings. I have set a 1-3us wait time around CS up/down to really slow things down for the Micron.

Comment: We can't guess what's wrong without seeing the schematics, code, or PCB layout. Please add these to the question.

Comment: The serial flash might not be the problem - it could be the microcontroller. Check the spi mode, setup and hold times.

Comment: @Kartman It works most of the time: the error occurs once every 1000 to 10000 write cycles which is why I do not think that it is that simple. And I checked these parameters a lot already.

Comment: @Justme The design is not as easy (part of a 10-processor system) which is why I do not have a simple schematic.

Comment: @Jens I don't care how complex the system is. What matters is the tiny bit with the SPI flash memory and the SPI bus to the MCU and code that communicates with the chip over SPI. Unless you use the SPI bus for other communications as well. Which then means everything on that SPI bus can cause problems when handled incorrectly.

Comment: We are in fact using the SPI bus (Clk, Miso, Mosi) as Master (for the Flash) and Slave (through an FPGA to another processor on a different board). This makes the analysis slightly more complex. Therefor I was hoping for some insight, which lane to the flash might take such a hit that the flash would expose the described behaviour. Even if MOSI for example would be disturbed, the data would certainly be wrong - but reading the status registers should work as neither of the components would see the disturbed data. Same with MISO: if status reading is disturbed, data upon readback should be ok.

Comment: @Jens Yeah you need to pinpoint what goes wrong and why, and it might be hopeless. If something corrupts the MOSI to flash, then flash sees invalid command and won't return correct response, if something corrupts MISO from flash then the response is corrupt even if command was OK. If clock gets corrupted then everything is wrong. You can't have a multimaster SPI bus without serious planning how to not corrupt transactions if anything can happen at any time.

Comment: You’ve got this weird problem, but you’re not telling us the full story. How can we possibly add value? I think you’ll find most skilled engineers use their powers of observation and hunt for evidence in order to solve seemingly complex problems. I’d suggest trying to debug just the serial flash and the microcontroller with nothing else on the spi bus. Cut pcb tracks if you have to. Have you tried a different serial flash chip just to rule that possibility out? It takes little time to remove and replace a 8pin chip.

Comment: I was going to suggest adding a logic analyzer at various places and changing the code to facilitate hardware debugging, but this isn't anything more than a suggestion and totally depends on the whole design.  Suggestions are discouraged in comments, but alas.

Comment: We'll be setting up a scope for Monday - hopefully, the issue does not go away by adding the equipment to the board. And if it does, we also know a little bit more. @rdtsc: We tested a different chip (Winbond) which does not have the same register set, but we also see occasionally corrupted data. But we do not see the inconsistency in the SPI replies.